# Why Does IE11 Send The Connection: Keep-Alive Request Header for HTTP 1.1 Requests?

Tags: internet-explorer, http-headers

Does anyone know why Internet Explorer 11 always sends the Connection: Keep-Alive request header, even for HTTP 1.1 requests (which are, by default, persistent and don't need/utilize the Connection header)?  Is this Microsoft's way of being backwards-compatible with HTTP 1.0?

Thanks For Your Help -